# Why method can't access class variable?

Tags: python

I am trying to understand variable scopes in Python, most of the things are clear to me except for the part that I don't understand why class variable is not accessible from its method.
In following example `mydef1()` can't access `a`, but if `a` is declared in global scope(outside class definition) it can.

```
class MyClass1:
    a = 25
    def mydef1(self):
        print(a)
ins1 = MyClass1()
ins1.mydef1()
```

Output

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\dev\Python\scope_test2.py", line 6, in <module>
    ins1.mydef1()
  File "E:\dev\Python\scope_test2.py", line 4, in mydef1
    print(a)
NameError: name 'a' is not defined
```

Comment: You can access a class variable by calling it `class.variable`. So, in your case, try `print(MyClass1.a)`.

Comment: `self.a` will also work, and is easier.

Comment: `self.a` might get confused with an instance variable, say: `temp = MyClass1; temp.a = 0`. You can still access the class variable through `MyClass1.a`, but `self.a` will change it's meaning.

Comment: Related: [In Python how can I access "static" class variables within class methods](//stackoverflow.com/q/707380)

Comment: Understood, but I expected that anything declared within class to be directly accessible, without `.` notation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's important to understand that some of these comments are not equivalent. `MyClass.a` is a member of the class itself, `self.a` is a member of the instance of the class.

When you use `self.a` it will return `a` from the class, because there is no `a` on the instance. If there was also an `a` which was a member of the instance, it would return that instead. Generally the instance a is set using the `__init__` constructor. Both of these can exist simultaneously.

```
class MyClass1:
    a = 25

    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 100

    def instance_a(self):
        print(self.a)

    def change_instance_a(self):
        self.a = 5

    def class_a(self):
        print(MyClass1.a)

    def change_class_a(self):
        MyClass1.a = 10


# Create two instances
ins1 = MyClass1()
ins2 = MyClass1()

# Both instances have the same Class member a, and the same instance member a
ins1.instance_a()
ins2.instance_a()
ins1.class_a()
ins2.class_a()

# Now lets change instance a on one of our instances
ins1.change_instance_a()

# Print again, see that class a values remain the same, but instance a has
# changed on one instance only
print()
ins1.instance_a()
ins2.instance_a()
ins1.class_a()
ins2.class_a()

# Lets change the class member a on just one instance
ins1.change_class_a()

# Both instances now report that new value for the class member a
print()
ins1.instance_a()
ins2.instance_a()
ins1.class_a()
ins2.class_a()
```

Answer (score 6):

Short answer: That's Python's scoping rules. Nested functions in Python are lexically scoped, but that doesn't apply to things nested in classes.

```
class Foo:
    a = 25
    print(a)
    class Bar:
        print(a)
```

The first one prints, but the second is a `NameError`.

---

Longer answer:

There *is* a function closure for class-level variables, but it is all wrapped in `__class__`. (The main use for this is in the `super()` magic, which is why it no longer needs arguments in Python 3.)

```
class MyClass1:
    a = 25
    def mydef1(self):
        print(__class__.a)
ins1 = MyClass1()
ins1.mydef1()  # 25
```

Normally, you'd access such things through the `self` parameter to allow subclasses to override them, but `__class__` would even work for a staticmethod, which has neither `self`, nor `cls`.

```
class MyClass1:
    a = 25
    @staticmethod
    def mydef1():
        print(__class__.a)
ins1 = MyClass1()
ins1.mydef1()  # 25
```

---

The class object technically doesn't even exist until *after* the class declaration finishes executing, that's why you can't do

```
class Foo:
    a = 25
    class Bar:
        # NameError: free variable '__class__' referenced before assignment
        print(__class__.a)
```

Nor even,

```
class Foo:
    a = 25
    def bar():
        print(__class__.a)
    # NameError: free variable '__class__' referenced before assignment in enclosing scope
    bar()
```

You can, however, access the `locals()` dict before then.

```
class Foo:
    a = 21
    locals()['a'] *= 2

Foo.a  # 42
```

So this works.

```
class Foo:
    a = 25
    global foolocals
    foolocals = locals()
    def bar():
        print(foolocals['a'])
    bar()  # 25
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following class:

```
class ScopeTest(object):
    classvariable = 0
    number_of_objects_created = 0

    def __init__(self, value=1):
        self.instancevariable = value
        ScopeTest.number_of_objects_created += 1

    def number_of_brothers(self):
        print(ScopeTest.number_of_objects_created)

    def confusion(self, value=2):
        self.classvariable = value
        print (f"class: {ScopeTest.classvariable}, self:{self.classvariable}")
```

And let's see what happens when you play around with it:

```
>>> a = ScopeTest()
>>> a.instancevariable
1
>>> a.classvariable
0
>>> ScopeTest.classvariable
0
```

So far so good, but when you assign a new attribute to `a`:

```
>>> a.classvariable = 2
>>> a.classvariable
2
>>> ScopeTest.classvariable
0
```

The same holds if you add the attribute inside a class's method:

```
>>> a.confusion(4)
class: 0, self:4
```

These kind of class attributes are good to keep things common to all objects, as the `number_of_objects_created`:

```
>>> b = ScopeTest()
>>> b.number_of_brothers()
2
>>> a.number_of_brothers()
2
```

You could get a little more from this by adding yet another method to the class:

```
class ScopeTest(object):
    ...
    def other_function(self, classvariable=3):
        print(f"class: {ScopeTest.classvariable}\t"
              f"instance: {self.classvariable}\t"
              f"argument:{classvariable}")
```

And calling it (after using the first 'confusion' method to set `self.classvariable`):

```
>>> a.confusion()
class: 0, self:2
>>> a.other_function()
class: 0        instance: 2     argument:3
```

Answer (score 1):

By calling `print(a)` in `mydef1`, python is looking for a local (or global, as you discovered) variable "`a`". That is, a variable not directly related to `MyClass1` in any way, but such a variable has not been defined yet.

If you're trying to access the *class variable* "`a`" (i.e. `a` is a member of the class itself, not any instance of it), you must use `MyClass1.a`. Alternatively, because there is no instance variable named "`a`", you can also use `self.a` to the same effect. However, as soon as `self.a` is explicitly defined, `self.a == MyClass1.a` may not be true. For example:

```
>>>class MyClass1:
...    a = 25
...
>>>my_obj = MyClass1()
>>>MyClass1.a
25
>>>my_obj.a
25
>>>MyClass1.a += 1
>>>MyClass1.a
26
>>>my_obj.a
26
>>>my_obj.a = 5  # explicitly define "a" for this instance; my_obj.a not longer synonymous with MyClass1.a
>>>MyClass1.a += 1
>>>MyClass1.a
27
>>>my_obj.a
5
```

Comment: Your answer made sense to me. Your statement "python is looking for a local (or global, as you discovered) variable "a". That is, a variable not directly related to MyClass1 in any way", cleared my doubt around this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need `self.a`.  There is no implicit class scope.