# Apparently inconsistent errors when calling functions defined in other modules from within a class

Tags: python

I understand this is the correct way to include a function in a class,
and works as desired:

```
from statsmodels.tsa.seasonal import seasonal_decompose

class Foo3:
    def my_seasonal_decompose(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # from statsmodels.tsa.seasonal import seasonal_decompose
        return seasonal_decompose(*args, **kwargs)

a3 = Foo3()
print(a3.my_seasonal_decompose([1, 2], period=1))
```

However, this works for `sin`, and not for `seasonal_decompose`. Why?

```
class Foo4:
    from numpy import sin
    from statsmodels.tsa.seasonal import seasonal_decompose


a4 = Foo4()
print(a4.sin(2))  # works

print(type(a4.seasonal_decompose))  # returns <class 'method'>
help(a4.seasonal_decompose)  # works as expected
print(a4.seasonal_decompose([1, 2], period=1))
# TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'Foo4'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `seasonal_decompose` is a `function` instance and `numpy.sin` is a `ufunc` instance. Both are *callable* and are used pretty much as functions, but only `seasonal_decompose` is treated as a *bona fide* Python function. And Python functions are treated special.

The `<class 'method'>` you're printing out should not be confused with *class methods* but that its *class* is `method`, more specifically a *bound method*. Bound methods are how Python wraps `function` instances to instance or class methods. Maybe a simple example will help:

```
def outerf(): pass # a true Python function

class Foo:
    f = outerf
    def g(self): pass


print(f)     # <function f at ...>
print(Foo.f) # <function outerf at ...>
print(Foo.g) # <function Foo.g at ...>
print()

x = Foo()
print(x.f) # <bound method outerf of <__main__.Foo object at ...>>
print(x.g) # <bound method Foo.g of <__main__.Foo object at ...>>
```

See how all of these start out as `function` instances in the class `Foo` but end up as bound methods in the `Foo` instance? When an instance is made, Python checks its class attributes for `function` instances and makes bound methods, no matter if the `function` was defined in the class or not.

So why does Python make bound methods? To implement instance method call syntax where the instance is automatically passed to the wrapped function's first argument.

```
f()
Foo.f()
Foo.g(x)

x.f() # TypeError: outerf() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given
x.g() # same as Foo.g(x)
```

Well okay, this is convenient and all, but what if you want to opt out? You want your function to stay a function in its instance and its class. Well that's what static methods are for. Now, you're not going to use the `@staticmethod` decorator here because decorators only work on function or class definitions, and your function is defined in another module. But you have the `staticmethod` builtin:

```
from statsmodels.tsa.seasonal import seasonal_decompose

class Foo4:
    my_seasonal_decompose = staticmethod(seasonal_decompose)

print(seasonal_decompose)         # <function seasonal_decompose at ...>
print(Foo4.my_seasonal_decompose) # <function seasonal_decompose at ...>
x4 = Foo4()
print(x4.my_seasonal_decompose)   # <function seasonal_decompose at ...>
```

Comment: The pointer to how to use `staticmethod` went beyond simply explaining the difference to providing an effective alternative. Additionally, your example was crucial to clearly understand.